# Como accedo al valor de una key de un diccionario PYTHON

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo la siguiente duda: me gustaria acceder a la llave o key de un diccionario sin acceder a su valor, por ejemplo:

```
clientes = {'001':{"Nombre":"Juan", "Telefono":"12345", "Direccion":"Calle 1"}}
```

Mi pregunta es sencilla y es como accedo el valor "001" para imprimirlo o modificarlo.(No quiero el valor que esta asociado a la llave, es decir, el nombre, el telefono y la direccion) sino al valor de la llave en si ("001")

Muchas gracias, saludos desde Argentina!

Comment: `clientes.keys()` te retorna una lista con las llaves del diccionario.

Comment: Hola @CandidMoe ! gracias por responder nuevamente en mis preguntas. Si eso lo se, lo que queria saber era como acceder a esa key en particular, lo pude hacer a traves de un for

Comment: Deberias evitar el uso del for cuando un metodo de los diccionarios te hace el trabajo mas rapido y optimo tal como lo indica @CandidMoe puedes usar el metodo keys(), Saludos

Comment: Hola @Jred0n29 y gracias tambien por responder. Pero al ser los diccionarios colecciones no ordenadas, no me sirve el iterador para claves, no es lo que necesito. no necesito una lista con todas las llaves. simplemente necesito imprimir la llave sola, y hasta ahora solo pude hacerlo a traves de un for

Comment: ¿Pero cómo identificas qué llave quieres cambiar? Podrías usar un for y dentro un if para verificar que es la llave que deseas cambiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código solo funciona para el caso de ese diccionario, pero si deseas obtener el nombre de la llave en otras situaciones debes hacer obligado un for y luego verificar la coincidencia de la llave:

```
clientes = {'001':{"Nombre":"Juan", "Telefono":"12345", "Direccion":"Calle 1"}}
list(clientes.keys())[0]
```

El output es:

> '001'

Answer (score 1):

Sí lo puedes hacer a través de un `for`:

```py
for key in clientes:
    print(key) # imprimes la key como tal
    print(clientes[key]) # imprimes el valor que contiene la key
```

Answer (score 1):

Muy sencillo, solo debes poner el nombre de la llave entre corchetes después del diccionario.

Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener el valor de la llave `'001'` haz lo siguiente:

```
clientes['001'] # {'Nombre': 'Juan', 'Telefono': '12345', 'Direccion': 'Calle 1'}
```

Como el resultado de `clientes['001']` es un diccionario, puedes por ejemplo acceder a la `'Direccion'` de la siguiente manera:

```
clientes['001']['Direccion'] # 'Calle 1'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! solo que tu respuesta no escucha a mi pregunta. Lo que quiero es obtener el valor '001', necesito imprimir literalmente la cadena "001", no el valor contenido adentro de la llave, necesito imprimir la llave en si, y hasta ahora solo pude hacerlo a traves de un for

Comment: Tu pregunta literalmente es Como accedo al **valor** de una key...

Comment: Hola @KazMiller te invito a que releas mi pregunta original... gracias por respnder.